# Add data to Redis on a distant server

Tags: node.js, redis

Beginner to redis here.

I'm trying to CRUD data from a distant redis server but I don't seem to make it work :

First we connect to the server :

```
const client = redis.createClient("the PORT", "the host", {auth_pass: "the password"});


(async () => {
    try {
      await client.connect();
      console.log('Connected to redis');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  })()
```

The connection seems to work, as I receive a
***Connected to redis*** in my terminal

But when I try to add data, it doesn't seem to work

```
app.get('/redis', (req, res) => {
    // set name to antoine on redis
    client.set('name', 'antoine', redis.print);
    // get name from redis
    client.get('name', (err, name) => {
        res.send(name);
    }
    );
});
```

The endpoint just load indefinitely as if it doesn't do the

```
client.get('name', (err, name) => {
        res.send(name);
    }
    );
```

And in my redis GUI, it shows ***No keys to display.***, so it didn't create the key either.

What am I missing here ?

EDIT : I just realized that instead of connecting to the distant server, I was connecting to my local one somehow.
Then, it seems that it doesn't connect to the distant.

EDIT2 : I forgot the async connect function, this is why it didn't work !

Comment: Did you try the URL attribute to connect `redis[s]://[[username][:password]@][host][:port][/db-number]`

Comment: Moreover do not forget the await in ```await client.set('name', 'antoine')```

Comment: @RahulK That's exactly what was wrong, and I forgot the async function, thank you !